# Convert a variable size hex string to signed number (variable size bytes) in C#

Tags: c#

C# provides the method `Convert.ToUInt16("FFFF", 16)`/`Convert.ToInt16("FFFF", 16)` to convert hex strings into unsigned and signed 16 bit integer. These methods works fine for 16/32 bit values but not so for 12 bit values.

I would like to convert 3 char long hex string to signed integer. How could I do it? I would prefer a solution that could take the number of character as parameter to decide signed values.

`Convert(string hexString, int fromBase, int size)`

- `Convert("FFF", 16, 12)` return `-1`.
- `Convert("FFFF", 16, 16)` return `-1`.
- `Convert("FFF", 16, 16)` return `4095`.

Comment: One of the examples here might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types

Comment: That parameter 16 is not the number of bits in the result, but the base in the supplied string. When you use 12 there, "F" is not a valid base-12 number

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: Look at the function signature in the question, OP clearly knows the differences between the base and the number of result bits, because he made two separate parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of converting 12 bit signed hex to a signed integer is as follows:

```
string value = "FFF";    
int convertedValue = (Convert.ToInt32(value, 16) << 20) >> 20; // -1
```

The idea is to shift the result as far left as possible so that the negative bits line up, then shift right again to the original position. This works because a "signed shift right" operation keeps the negative bit in place.

You can generalize this into a method as follows:

```
int Convert(string value, int fromBase, int bits)
{
    int bitsToShift = 32 - bits;
    return (Convert.ToInt32(value, fromBase) << bitsToShift) >> bitsToShift;
}
```

You can cast the result to a `short` if you want a 16 bit value when working with 12 bit hex strings. Performance of this method will be the same as a 16 bit version because bit shift operators on `short` cast the values to `int` anyway and this gives you more flexibility to specify more than 16 bits if needed without writing another method.

Comment: Rather than string concatenation (which only works for integral hex digits / multiples of 4 bits anyway), it's far more efficient to left-shift, cast, then right-shift.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first part (integral digits / multiples of 4) but good point about string, answer updated.

Comment: I just meant that if you happened to have an input that represented a 21 bit number (`0x000000` - `0x1FFFFF`), there would be no way to line up the sign bit using string manipulation.  With bitwise shift operators, it's easy to move the sign 11 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you'd like to calculate the [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for a certain number of bits (12 in your case, but really it should work with anything).

Here's the code in C#, blatantly stolen from the Python example in the wiki article:

```
int Convert(string hexString, int fromBase, int num_bits)
{
    var i = System.Convert.ToUInt16(hexString, fromBase);
    var mask = 1 << (num_bits - 1);
    return (-(i & mask) + (i & ~mask));
}
```

- `Convert("FFF", 16, 12)` returns `-1`
- `Convert("4095", 10, 12)` is also `-1` as expected